# How do I undo changes from "Replace in files" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a huge problem. I need to undo all the files becouse I've changed from ' to " the whole project. How do I return that back in VS code

Comment: Well, luckily your project is properly source controlled, and you can just check out the previous version, right? Anything else is grounds for immediate termination.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your file name in VS code, For Eg:

index.html -> right click -> timeline

when you click on time line, it will show all the previous versions of the file

you can simply copy the previous version of your code...cheers !!!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAVyO.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can just undoing the changes in one file, and it will undo that in all other files.